# Change text Upsell in Magento Product Edit (admin page)

Tags: magento

Where I can change the "Up-sell" Text on product edit backend (admin page)?
I try to change core file on tabs. But it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to change label from app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php file.

```
$this->addTab('upsell', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Up-sells'),
                'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/upsell', array('_current' => true)),
                'class'     => 'ajax',
            ));
```

If it is not working then it means some other file has overridden the code.
look if you have any such file
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php 
OR 
search this class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs.some file either in community or in local pool has extended this class.

Another possibility is that there is some unusual coding(compare with file from fresh magento) in your template file 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/tabs.phtml 
OR some other template file overriding above file.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be adding to the locale translate file. Edit this file:

`/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/locale/en_US/translate.csv`

scroll to the bottom of that .csv add the following line:

`"Up-sells", "New Label Name"`

If you are worried about upgrading your Magento install later will need to create a new theme folder inside that same package and add your modified translate.csv there, this way you can keep your edits and changes on this new theme, example:

`/app/design/adminhtml/default/my-theme/locale/en_US/translate.csv`

Answer (score 0):

For those who have navigated to this page in order to change the product pages/ the frontend, (ex: how to change "Upselling Product(s)" or "Related products" or even "Cross sell" in Magento), here is my 5 minute fix!

1. Go to System Tab.
2. Scroll all the way down to Configuration.
3. Scroll down to the bottom left and click Developer.
4. Under the tab "Translate inline", select "yes" for the "Enabled for Frontend" dropdown.
5. Go to the page you want to change the text; it should be highlighted in red.
6. When you get near the red boxes, an icon of an open book shows up.
7. Click that to allow yourself to make changes to Mage_Catalog without fumbling around for tabs and phps.
8. Be sure to go back and switch Enabled for Fronted to "no" or hooligans can go in and change everything on your webpage ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `config.xml`

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
            <observers>
                <Your_Module>
                    <class>Your_Module/Observer_ProductAdminTabs</class>
                    <method>execute</method>
                </Your_Module>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Create an observer with the following;

```
public function execute(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getData('block');
    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs) {
         $block->removeTab('related');
         $block->setTabData('upsell', 'label', Mage::helper('catalog')->__('[New Name Here]'));
    }
}
```